# Facebook Open Graph test user profile object error code:1611016

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-test-users

I am submitting an action with an object which has a few properties using Open Graph. One of the properties is a another test user's profile. Same code works fine for actual users but when it comes to the test users Open Graph will return :

```
... the given value 'http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/profile.php?id=100003943905026' 
for property 'profile1' could not be parsed as type 'profile'.","code":1611016
```

I assume that the app or open graph or facebook can not see the test user's profile.

The test user's profile is:
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100003943905026

Which of course you can not see it but the test user and his friends can see the profile.

Any suggestion on how to send a test user's profile using open graph?

I assume there should be a key or special URL for that but so far I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/228470197239393?browse=search_4f23cd4008c9f0156444558) in Facebook, due to which Test Users can't publish Open Graph actions in Sandbox Mode.

Comment: actually my test users can publish actions. The only issue is that their profile address looks invalid for Open Graph.

Answer (score 0):

A bug is opened here : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/100992683376664
Do not hesitate to mention you can reproduce